# Blueprism - Can I store more than one excel workbook in one handle?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a process that catch and set data from 3 different xls files.
Shoud I create a new instance every time I open one of them or I can store more than one "workbook name" in only one handle data item without crashing into an error?

Comment: You mean to say that you want to open more than 1 Workbook in one instance?

Comment: Precisely @rajesh-s